# FatalErrorException: Call to a member function getFirstName() on null

Tags: symfony-2.5

Please help me

> in C:\xampp\htdocs\project_sms\src\Com\AkSolutions\Sms\UserBundle\Form\Type\UserSendMessageType.php at line 55

```
$form = $event->getForm();
$form->getData()->setFromUserId($this->user->getId());
$form->getData()->setFromName($this->userProfile->getFirstName()."".$this->userProfile->getLastName());
$form->getData()->setUserType($this->userType);
$form->getData()->setReadStatus(false);
$form->getData()->setDeleteStatus(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
$this->userProfile->getFirstName()
```

specifically the error is telling you that this expression:

```
$this->userProfile
```

is null

Comment: Thanks to Trevor Brown